# UIstoryboard: Animates option for Modal segues is not available on iOS versions prior to 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, uistoryboard

I'm getting the above warnings using Xcode 5 with a deployment target set to iOS 5.0.

I'm not sure whether to simply ignore these warnings OR find an alternative way of providing this functionality for iOS5.

As far as I can see I have a number of imperfect solutions:

Option 1: present the MainStoryboard programmatically for iOS6+; replace modal segues on a different storyboard  for iOS5 with

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

Option2: would be to drop modal segues entirely from the storyboard(s), calling any segues within IBAction methods

Option3: ignore the warnings (would the app still be accepted?).

(Yes, I'm aware of "target iOS6+ only" as an option)

I'd appreciate advice from those who've found ways to solve this problem.

Update: solved this thanks to Mikael's answer below:
I subclassed UIStoryboardSegue as below

```
#import "StandardModalSegue.h"

@implementation StandardModalSegue
- (void) perform {
    //my conditional version of NSLog()
    myLog(kLogVC, 2, @"%@ to %@",self.sourceViewController ,self.destinationViewController);
    //iOS5 replacement for presentModalViewController:animated:
    [self.sourceViewController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

and used it in storyboard thus

[image]

PS: accepting Mikael's answer, this here to help newbies like me!

Comment: How are you setting up your segue? The issue is not that the segue is modal but with the animation. iOS5 included modal segues.

Comment: @Mikael, I have 5 modal segues all with the Animates option turned off. I therefore assumed that the warning arises cos the storyboard xml reads (e.g.)"<segue destination="ReA-n1-Gz2" kind="modal" identifier="segueToActionVCtype_1" modalTransitionStyle="crossDissolve" animates="NO" id="tfl-qt-QkC"/>" rather than not having an animates="BOOL" option at all.

Comment: I just put an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the animate checkbox in interface builder that creates this error. If you want to get rid of it and not animate your modal segue you need to create a custom segue and override `-(void) perform`

All you have to do is keep the segues you have now but set them to custom. Then you create a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue. In the implementation file you put:

```
- (void)perform
{
// Add your own animation code here.

    [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}
```

You can then use this segue like any other segue. If it's attached to a UIButton it gets called automatically and you do not need performSegue. If not you can use the performSegue that is compatible with iOS5 or even choose a performSegue depending on the version of OS.

Comment: Thanks, Mikael,  I'll check that out; I assumed that as  under "Creating a Custom Segue:
+ segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:" it says "Available in iOS 6.0 and later" it would throw an error in iOS5. Not sure what you mean by override -(void) perform,  but I'll get back to you once  I've checked it out.

Comment: You don't need `segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:` you can just use it like a normal segue. I will add more detail to my answer about overriding `-(void) perform`

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I figure it out then saw your helpful (accepted) edit. I'll now look into appropriate animation code. Still think it's odd that `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is available in iOS5 but the compiler complains about its storyboard equivalent!